# cv_bridge memory issues

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having problems with memory when it comes to using the cv_ptr->image from [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages). How would I copy the image to use it as an IplImage* for the rest of the program so that I can release all data at the end?

This is my latest attempt - imageBGR is for altering, imageRaw is the raw image to be sent around to a few functions/callbacks etc.

```
void ImageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg)
{
   cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
   try {
   cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
   }
   catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e){
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
   }

   IplImage* imageRaw, *imageBGR;
   imageRaw = cvCreateImage( cvSize(640,480) ,IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
   *imageRaw = cv_ptr->image;
   imageBGR = cvCloneImage( imageRaw );
   //do stuff
   cvReleaseImage( &imageBGR );
}
```

I can't use CvMat because I'm using an obsolete package that takes in IplImage*.

I get the following error after running the code above for a bit

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I release the imageRaw image, then I get a segmentation fault and this output from valgrind

```
==11677== Invalid read of size 4
==11677==    at 0x4229CD6: boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<cv_bridge::CvImage*, boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<cv_bridge::CvImage> >::dispose() (mat.hpp:366)
==11677==    by 0x807781D: boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() (shared_count.hpp:217)
==11677==    by 0x80787FF: boost::shared_ptr<cv_bridge::CvImage>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.hpp:168)
==11677==    by 0x8073D99: ImageCb(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (state_sensor.cpp:173)
==11677==    by 0x807DCA8: boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (function_template.hpp:112)
==11677==    by 0x4759603: image_transport::RawSubscriber::internalCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4756802: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
==11677==    by 0x474C965: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x475FBFE: ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperCallParams&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4128C06: ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40D8A86: ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40DA563: ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==  Address 0x1ca8f500 is 921,616 bytes inside a block of size 921,624 free'd
==11677==    at 0x402C06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==11677==    by 0x43EE3D1: cv::fastFree(void*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==11677==    by 0x807DCA8: boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (function_template.hpp:112)
==11677==    by 0x4759603: image_transport::RawSubscriber::internalCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4756802: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
==11677==    by 0x474C965: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x475FBFE: ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperCallParams&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4128C06: ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40D8A86: ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40DA563: ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x411039A: ros::spinOnce() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x48FF4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==11677== 
==11677== Invalid read of size 4
==11677==    at 0x43EE3C7: cv::fastFree(void*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==11677==    by 0x807781D: boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() (shared_count.hpp:217)
==11677==    by 0x80787FF: boost::shared_ptr<cv_bridge::CvImage>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.hpp:168)
==11677==    by 0x8073D99: ImageCb(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (state_sensor.cpp:173)
==11677==    by 0x807DCA8: boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (function_template.hpp:112)
==11677==    by 0x4759603: image_transport::RawSubscriber::internalCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4756802: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
==11677==    by 0x474C965: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x475FBFE: ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperCallParams&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4128C06: ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40D8A86: ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40DA563: ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==  Address 0x1c9ae4fc is 12 bytes inside a block of size 921,624 free'd
==11677==    at 0x402C06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==11677==    by 0x43EE3D1: cv::fastFree(void*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==11677==    by 0x807DCA8: boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (function_template.hpp:112)
==11677==    by 0x4759603: image_transport::RawSubscriber::internalCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4756802: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
==11677==    by 0x474C965: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x475FBFE: ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperCallParams&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4128C06: ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40D8A86: ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40DA563: ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x411039A: ros::spinOnce() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x48FF4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==11677== 
==11677== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==11677==    at 0x402C06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==11677==    by 0x43EE3D1: cv::fastFree(void*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==11677==    by 0x807781D: boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() (shared_count.hpp:217)
==11677==    by 0x80787FF: boost::shared_ptr<cv_bridge::CvImage>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.hpp:168)
==11677==    by 0x8073D99: ImageCb(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (state_sensor.cpp:173)
==11677==    by 0x807DCA8: boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (function_template.hpp:112)
==11677==    by 0x4759603: image_transport::RawSubscriber::internalCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4756802: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
==11677==    by 0x474C965: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x475FBFE: ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperCallParams&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4128C06: ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40D8A86: ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==  Address 0x1c9ae4f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 921,624 free'd
==11677==    at 0x402C06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==11677==    by 0x43EE3D1: cv::fastFree(void*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==11677==    by 0x807DCA8: boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (function_template.hpp:112)
==11677==    by 0x4759603: image_transport::RawSubscriber::internalCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4756802: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<image_transport::SimpleSubscriberPlugin<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) (mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
==11677==    by 0x474C965: boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void ()(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x475FBFE: ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperCallParams&) (function_template.hpp:1013)
==11677==    by 0x4128C06: ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40D8A86: ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x40DA563: ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x411039A: ros::spinOnce() (in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)
==11677==    by 0x48FF4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==11677==
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44973/cv_bridge-memory-issues/) by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are first creating an image with cvCreateImage and then overwriting the pointer rawImage by cv_ptr->image. That's probably your memory leak. Why aren't you just cloning the image in cv_ptr? `imageBGR = cvCloneImage( &cv_ptr->image );`

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you are not releasing the `*ImageRaw` memory. Every time your callback returns, it loses that image.

EDIT: my original answer above was wrong. For future reference: @Lorenz is correct: clone the image, don't over-write an existing pointer.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-10-02**:
Already tried that, I get a segmentation fault so I removed it - the cv_ptr->image cannot be released apparently.

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-10-04**:
The segmentation fault actually occurs after the callback scope. It seems like, inside the function, I free 921,624 bytes of image data. And after the function boost, ROS and OpenCV processes release memory 0, 12 and 921,616 bytes into that free'd memory block, respectively. Any ideas?

**Comment by [ocli](https://answers.ros.org/users/2452/ocli/) on 2012-10-04**:
Hmm, that did seem to be the problem, but I thought I had done that in the past. As a side, do you know why it takes a while to process the point cloud from the openni package? between any other callback and a callback involving sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 there is a significant delay